# MySQL: how to search for a number that might not be unique

Tags: mysql, search

I'll try to make it easy by explaining an example.

So, I consolidate data from two sources, namely 1 and 2. In each of the sources, it has a column "number" that has unique values within a source. But when A and B are consolidated (they have to be), it cannot be checked that they are unique. However, when consolidating 1 and 2, I created a column name "source" and tagged it with its source name (1 or 2). Therefore, if I want to look for a certain specific "number" I submit a query that looks for the desired number AND source.

Is there a better way to do this? It is working just fine because my database is small, but will this work well (i.e. fast, efficiently, etc.) as the DB grows? I mean, it won't have one million entries in the next few years, but I'd still like to perform it in a optimal manner.

The only other way I can think about is to keep separate "number" columns for different sources and query the appropriate columns.. but this will require additional columns to be added as I get additional sources. Hm.. what to do?

Comment: I hope this "number" can be big like 99999999 and 1000000 if you have thousands of records and before inserting if you have to check all these rows it will surely slow down. but no other way i can think of !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should work just fine without causing any perceivable slow downs, if any at all.